# Chef on AWS: How do you update the certificate on the server?

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, configuration, server, chef-infra

I am trying to use knife from my laptop to connect to a newly configured Chef server hosted on AWS. I know what is listed below is the right direction for me but I'm not sure how to go about this exactly.

```
If you are not able to connect to the server using the hostname ip-xx-x-x-xx.ec2.internal 
you will have to update the certificate on the server to use the correct hostname.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this same problem. The problem is that EC2 instances place their private ip into their hostname file. Which causes chef to self assign certs to the internal ip. When you do `knife ssl check` you'll probably get an error message that looks like this:

```
ERROR: The SSL cert is signed by a trusted authority but is not valid for the given hostname
ERROR: You are attempting to connect to:   'ec2-x-x-x-x.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com'
ERROR: The server's certificate belongs to 'ip-y-y-y-y.us-west-2.compute.internal'
```

connecting to the public IP is correct however you'll continue to get this error if you don't configure your chef server to use your public dns when signing the cert.

**EDIT:** Chef's documentation used to have steps to correct this issue, but since the time I initially answered this question they have removed those steps from their tutorial. The following steps worked for me with Chef 12, Ubuntu 16 on an ec2 instance.

1. ssh onto your chef server
2. open your hostname file with the following command `sudo vim /etc/hostname`
3. remove the line containing you internal ip and replace it with your public ip and save the file.
4. reboot the server with `sudo reboot`
5. run `sudo chef-server-ctl reconfigure` (this signs a new certificate, among other things)
6. Go back to your workstation and use `knife ssl fetch` followed by `knife ssl check` and you should be good to go.

What you could ALSO do, is just complete steps 1 - 4 before you even install chef onto the server.

Comment: [this](https://docs.chef.io/aws_marketplace.html#configure-the-chef-server-title) has some info that may be useful to this particular issue. I'll look for a more comparable article though.

Comment: @PawełSkorupiński I edited my answer, sorry I can't provide the same or similar article as a reference. Best advice I can offer is to follow Chef's tutorials and documentation to the letter, because I had this issue when I skipped over details.

Comment: @PawełSkorupiński I'm updating this answer with necessary steps to correct this issue.

Answer (score 1):

- Update public IP on Chef Server
- run chef-server-ctl reconfigure on Server (No reboot needed)
- Update the knife.rb on Workstation with new IP address
- run 'knife ssl fetch' on the Chef Workstation

This should resolve the issue, to confirm run 'knife client list'

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect to an internal IP (or DNS that points to an internal IP) from outside AWS. Those are [nonroutable IP addresses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918).

Instead, connect to the public IP of the instance, if you have one.

Comment: I do have my knife configuration file pointing to my public IP. When I attempt to go to the public IP in my browser (Chrome) the https is crossed out and I have a certification error. My certification on the server is generated off of the private IP not the public could this be the issue?